# MEAN: can I register more than a mini router app in app.use()?

Tags: node.js, angular, express, router

In my node/express app.js main file, I have created a mini-app router:

```
var router = express.Router();
```

that I am passing inside to my controller functions and exporting again, at the end, I am registering the router in

```
app.use('/Link', router);
```

I now wanted to set up a second Controller folder with extra Controller function and routes only for my Angular NGX-Charts, where I prep up my data from mongoDB in correct format. Therefore, I wanted to create a second router object where I am passing and registering the right routes and middleware for that router object.

My question now is, can I create and register more than one router object for my express instance, like `app.use('/Link',router1, router2, router3,...)` ?
and does it behave the same like one router object then (I mean, will it find the appropriate router according to which routes I am navigating to in my browser and execute the correct middleware)?

Comment: No, you can't do that. It's unlikely that you really need `app.use('/Link',router1, router2, router3,...)`. It's unclear what you're trying to achieve with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, you can do that. Common use-cases would be password-protection, generating auth tokens, parsing payloads, etc.

`app.use` accepts any number of "middlewares" after the first argument.

Check the docs for more details: https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#app.use

The arguments are fairly flexible, there are a number of options for what you can pass.

- A middleware function.
- A series of middleware functions (separated by commas).
- An array of middleware functions.
- A combination of all of the above.

Each function gets 3 arguments, which are the Request, Response, and next callback function. Here's an example with an inline middleware that logs something and forwards to the next handler.

```
app.use('/secret-stuff', authorize, (req, res, next) => {
    console.log('token from auth middleware', req.authToken)
    next()
}, render)
```

One thing to note is that you can only send one response, so only the final handler would send the response to the user. Everything before that should call `next()` to activate the next middleware in the chain.

You could pass a number of routers as long as you make sure to forward (call `next()`) when the paths are unmatched. You would need to use some kind of path pattern that would allow for the middleware routers to handle greater specificity in the path (e.g. '/Link/*'), otherwise you wouldn't be able to define any sub-path handlers in the middleware routers.

In the past, I haven't had the need for sub-routers. Middleware works fine for modularization.

Comment: hi, one more question, can I also register my routers on different app routes? e.g app.use('/link1', router1); app.use('link2', router2); etc...?